# Regex to get String array by splitting with operators ( ! , & , ( , ) , | ) with all string's start and end position In Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I am new to regex , I want to get string array with all string's start position and end position by splitting operator ( **!** , **&** , **(** , **)** , **|** ) .

Examples:

```
1.  !(AString&BString)|CString
    0123456789

Output should be String Array with all string's start position and end position: 
[AString,BString,CString...]
Every String Position:
AString (7 length) => 2 to 8
BString => 10 to 16
CString => 19 to 25


2.  (AString)&(BString)|!(CString)
3.  !(AString|BString)&CString
4.  !(AString&(!(BString|CString))|DString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting, you could do matching. `[^()!&|]+` matches any character but not of `(` or `)` or `|` or `!` or `&` one or more times. Then find the start and end index of each match using `matcherobj.start()` and `matcherobj.end()` functions.

```
String s1 = "!(AString&BString)|CString";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^()!&|]+").matcher(s1);
while(m.find())
{

System.out.println(m.group() + "  => " + m.start() +  " to " + (m.end()-1));

}
```

**Output:**

```
AString  => 2 to 8
BString  => 10 to 16
CString  => 19 to 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Strings Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method:

```
String givenString= "!(AString&BString)|CString";
String[] stringArray= givenString.split("[!()&|]");//modify regular expression according to your need
```

This will give me your array which contains element as you wanted plus other element as `""`.