# String validation for operators like & , !, ),(, | through regex

Tags: java, regex, string, validation

I am totally new to reg-ex and I want to get validation for the `string` for valid combination of logical operators like ( **!** , **&** , **(** , **)** , **|** ) . for Example if **& |**  combined than it should be invalid as `AND OR` should come together. likewise possible invalid combination are **&|**, **|&** , **()**, **!&** ,**&!** etc

like example of below String

```
1.  (ABC)&(DFG)|!(ZXC) - pass because all operators are correctly combined
2.  !(ABC|DKJ)&VBN - pass
3.  !(ADF&(!&(BER|CTY))|DGH) = failed as !& combined
4.  !(ABC&DKJ)&|VBN - failed as & | combined
```

I know their several ways like I can use `String's` `contains` method to get check and reject if not passed the validation. But I am looking for solution through `reg-ex` in `java`

Comment: You may want to look into Java's `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes. The API for `Pattern` especially contains very helpful information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Use a parser generator like http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression

Comment: Are you trying to solve same homework or what: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076008/regex-to-get-string-array-by-splitting-with-operators-with?

Comment: @Pshemo good observation but My task is to validate

Comment: And do you have to use regex here? It looks like http://www.antlr.org/ may be better tool for that.

Comment: don't use regex for tough task..i think `|&` also an invalid combination.

Comment: @AvinashRaj than what would be the right approach ?

Comment: @LutzHorn can you please provide solution of my question using antlr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to avoid matching invalid operator combos you can use negative lookahead regex like this:

```
^(?!.*?(&\\||\\|&|\\(\\)|!&|&!))
```

Use it with `MULTILINE` option like this for multiline inputs:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?m)^(?!.*?(&[!|]|[(|]&|\\(\\)))" );
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zR8lC0/1)

**For using it with a string input you can do:**

```
boolean value = input.matches( "(?!.*?(&[!|]|[(|]&|\\(\\))).+" );
```

Comment: how to use it in a method sorry but please guide me as m totally new to regex

Comment: ok check my edited answer on using `String#matches` with above regex.

Comment: Although I agree with your approach, I don't think the OP should actually follow this.. Having braces will always lead to *corner cases* :)

Comment: @anubhava thanks but sitll testing all the possible combinations as soon as all will completed I will upvote this masterpiece

Comment: @anubhava it gives pass this test ideally it should not `!(ABC|DKJ)(&VBN` here )( are invalid combination

Comment: Check updated regex, I had just based on your list of invalid combos in question.